# change background image url on hover with css

Tags: html, css

i have a ribbon on bottom of every report page with an image for call window.print().

i figure out it like this:

```
<div id="dgdPrint" class="hop">
 <div id="dgdPrnImg" title="Print Report..." onclick="window.print();">
 </div>
</div>
```

and i style it with:

```
#dgdPrint 
 { position:fixed; 
   border-top:1px solid #000; 
   width:100%; 
   bottom:0; 
   right:0; 
   text-align:center; 
   height:55px; 
   margin-top:50px; 
   background-color:#88A7DB; }

#dgdPrnImg 
 { margin-top:10px;
   background-image:url('PrinterText.png'); 
   background-position:center center;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   height:35px; }

#dgdPrnImg:hover
 { background-image:url('PrinterText-hover.png'); }
```

but whole of first div (ribbon) take this effect and on hover of any part of that the image is changed. what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It changes because you have `background-image:url('PrinterText-hover.png'); }` set under `#dgdPrnImg:hover`

Comment: #dgdPrnImg has an background image and on over it, it's change to another image, is it wrong?

Comment: Maybe i didnt understand your question correctly. From what I read, you're asking what's wrong with your code because when you hover the background image changes.

"but whole of first div (ribbon) take this effect and on hover of any part of that the image is changed. what's wrong in my code?"

Comment: the div dgdPrnImg is a 35px div in the middle of dgdPrint div (the 100% width div that is parent of dgdPrnImg). but image url change when dgdPrint hover occure. can u say why?